# Books on limiting properties of matrices with growing size

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, reference-request

I am studying asymptotic   properties of the [Projection Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix)
$$
H_n=X'(X'X)^{-1}X
$$
By the Gerschgorin disc theorem, the bounds on the eigenvalues of $H_g$
\begin{align*}
 \min_i(h_{ii}-\sum^{n}_{j\neq i} |h_{ij}|)\leq \rho(H_n)\leq \max_i(h_{ii,g}+\sum^{n}_{j\neq i} |h_{ij}|)
 \end{align*}
Since $h_{ij}^2\leq h_{ii}h_{jj}$, (see Chatterjee and Hadi, 1998),  if the matrix satisfies
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \max_i h_{ii}=0\implies  \rho(H_{\infty})=0
 \end{align*}
Is the above reasoning valid? If someone could provide me with the books on sequence of growing matrices and the tools to compute their limiting properties that would be great.I have seen [papers](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82817688.pdf) like this in the internet which is very relevant but could not find a textbook on this topic.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. It seems as though you're trying to prove the following statement: "if $H_n$ is a sequence of projection matrices such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \max_i [H_n]_{ii} = 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \rho(H_\infty) = 0$", and you want to know whether your reasoning constitutes a correct proof. Is that correct? If I interpreted your question correctly, then yes: your reasoning is valid.

Comment: Yes, Ben. That is exactly what i am asking.I would like to read more about maths behind this. What exactly is $H_\infty$ and what exactly is the eigenvalue of $H_\infty$? Do you interpret these as bounded linear operator?

Comment: I'm missing some information that I would need to answer that. What exactly is the size of the matrix $X$? If $H_n$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then it is very unclear what $H_\infty$ is suppose to be

Comment: $X$ would be a $n\times p$ where $p<n$. I am seeking a well defined notion for $H_\infty$.